# Changes to estimates on predicates that contain SUBSTRING() in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2016, substring, cardinality-estimates

Is there any documentation or research about changes in SQL Server 2016 to how cardinality is estimated for predicates containing SUBSTRING() or other string functions?

The reason I'm asking is that I was looking at a query whose performance degraded in compatibility mode 130 and the reason was related a change in the estimate of the number of rows that match a WHERE clause that contained a call to SUBSTRING(). I corrected the problem with a query rewrite, but am wondering if anyone is aware of any documentation about changes in this area in SQL Server 2016.

Demo code is below. The estimates are very close in this test case, but the accuracy varies depending on the data.

In the test case, in compat level 120, SQL Server appears to be using the histogram for the estimate, whereas in compat level 130 SQL Server appears to be assuming a fixed 10% of the table matches.

```
CREATE DATABASE MyStringTestDB;
GO
USE MyStringTestDB;
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.StringTest;
CREATE TABLE dbo.StringTest ( [TheString] varchar(15) );
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'Y5_CLV' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'Y5_EG3' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'ZY_NE' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'ZY_PQT' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'ZY_T2V' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'ZY_TT4' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'ZY_ZKK' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'ZZ_LW6' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'ZZ_QO3' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'ZZ_TZ7' );
INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
VALUES
( 'ZZ_UZZ' );

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Clustered ON dbo.StringTest (TheString);

/* 
Uses fixed % for estimate; 1.1 rows estimated in this case.
    Plan for computation:
        CSelCalcFixedFilter (0.1) <----
            Selectivity: 0.1
*/
ALTER DATABASE MyStringTestDB SET compatibility_level = 130;
GO
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.StringTest 
WHERE SUBSTRING(TheString, 1, CHARINDEX('_',TheString) - 1) = 'ZZ'
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 2363, QUERYTRACEON 3604);

/* 
Uses histogram to get estimate of 1
 CSelCalcPointPredsFreqBased <----
      Distinct value calculation:
          CDVCPlanLeaf
              0 Multi-Column Stats, 1 Single-Column Stats, 0 Guesses
      Individual selectivity calculations:
          (none)
    Loaded histogram for column QCOL: [DBA].[dbo].[StringTest].TheString from stats with id 1
*/
ALTER DATABASE MyStringTestDB SET compatibility_level = 120;
GO
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.StringTest 
WHERE SUBSTRING(TheString, 1, CHARINDEX('_',TheString) - 1) = 'ZZ'
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 2363, QUERYTRACEON 3604);

/*
-- Simpler rewrite; works fine in both compat levels and gets better estimate.
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.StringTest 
WHERE TheString LIKE 'ZZ[_]%'
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 2363, QUERYTRACEON 3604);
*/
```

Comment: Not sure about the particular question, but if the `Y5_EG3` strings are just codes and always upper-case, then you can always try specifying a binary collation -- `Latin1_General_100_BIN2` -- which should improve speed on filtering operations. Just add `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2` to the `CREATE TABLE` statement, just after the `varchar(15)`. I would be curious to see if it also affected the plan generation / estimation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46690/discussion-between-james-lupolt-and-martin-smith).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of any documentation. I did look into this and make some observations however that are too long for a comment.

The 10% estimate is not always a degradation. Take the following example.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.StringTest

INSERT INTO dbo.StringTest
SELECT TOP (1000000) 'ZZ_' + LEFT(NEWID(), 12)
FROM   master..spt_values v1,
       master..spt_values v2;
```

and the `WHERE` clause in your question.

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(TheString, 1, CHARINDEX('_',TheString) - 1) = 'ZZ'
```

The table contains a million rows. All of them match the predicate. Under compat level 130 the 10% guess yields an estimate of 100,000. Under 120 the estimated rows is 1.03913.

The 120 behaviour uses the histogram but only to get the number of distinct rows. The density vector in my case shows 1.039131E-06 and this is multiplied by the table cardinality to get the estimated row count. All of the values are in fact different but all match the predicate.

Tracing the `query_optimizer_estimate_cardinality` extended event shows that under 130 there are two different `<StatsCollection Name="CStCollFilter"` events. The first one estimates 100,000. The second one loads the histogram and uses the CSelCalcPointPredsFreqBased/DistinctCountCalculator to get the 1.04 estimate. This second result appears unused.

The behavior that you observed is not consistently applied in 130. I added `ORDER BY TheString` expecting this to be a clear win for the 130 estimator as the 120 struggles on with a memory grant for one row but this minor change was sufficient to bring the estimated rows down to 1.03913 in the 130 case too.

Adding `OPTION  (QUERYRULEOFF SelectToFilter)` reverts the estimate going into the sort to 100,000 but the memory grant doesn't increase and the estimates coming out the sort are still based on the table distinct values.

[image]

Similarly tweaking the cost threshold for parallelism so that the query gets a parallel plan was sufficient in the 130 case to revert to the lower estimate. Adding `QUERYTRACEON 8757` also causes the lower estimate. It looks like the 10% estimate is only retained for trivial plans.

Your proposed rewrite with

```
WHERE TheString LIKE 'ZZ[_]%'
```

Shows much superior estimates to both. The output for this is

```
  CSelCalcTrieBased

      Column: QCOL: [MyStringTestDB].[dbo].[StringTest].TheString
```

Showing that it used [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). More info about this is in the string summary statistics section just above [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd535534(v=sql.100).aspx#code-snippet-11).

It is not the same as your original query however. As the first instance of `_` is now assumed to always be the third character rather than being found dynamically.

If this assumption is hardcoded into your original query

```
 WHERE SUBSTRING(TheString, 1, 3) = 'ZZ_'
```

The estimation method changes to `CSelCalcHistogramComparison(INTERVAL)` and the estimated rows become accurate.

It is able to convert that into a range

```
WHERE TheString >=  'ZZ_' AND TheString < ???
```

and use the histogram to estimate the number of rows with values in that range.

This applies only to the cardinality estimation however. `LIKE` is preferable as it can use a range seek at runtime. `SUBSTRING(TheString, 1, 3)` or `LEFT(TheString, 3)` can't.